# how to convert (3 digit) Decimal to Ascii from textbox.text?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

when i inpot Decimal numbers to textbox, the output will be one word

EX:

input:

textbox.text = `11311711511597105`

output:

textbox.text = `qussai`

Comment: The `97` is 2-digits.

Comment: suppose that may decimal number like this:
113117115115097105
I need code in vb, plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show us what you had tried.

The full code should be like this:

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim output As String = DecimalToASCII("113117115115097105")
        Console.WriteLine(output)
    End Sub

    Function DecimalToASCII(ByVal input As String) As String
        Dim current As String = ""
        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        If input.Length Mod 3 <> 0 Then
            Return "Wrong Input"
        End If
        For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1 Step 3
            temp = 0
            For j As Integer = i To i + 2
                temp *= 10
                temp += CType(input(j).ToString(), Integer)
            Next
            current &= Chr(temp).ToString()
        Next
        Return current
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: OK thanks, ^_^ .
could you give me how to convert string to Decimal provided that if decimal of character less than three digit, add 0 zero on the left, and do some operation and collect them in textbox.text?

EX:
a in Ascii equal 97
i want it like this
097
and then
097 ^5 mod 5
the final result will be like this:
2
.

Comment: This code for convert from Ascii to decimal, but i couldn't add zero on left of (2 digit)


`code`
Dim sText As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim lenText As Integer
        sText = TextBox6.Text
        lenText = Len(sText)
        For i = 1 To lenText
            sASC = sASC & CStr(Asc(Mid$(sText, i, 1)))
        Next i
        m = sASC
`code`

Comment: @qussai I'ts not impossible to parse only 2-digits, since there will be conflict characters.

Comment: @qussai So what are you trying to do here? Can you show me why you want to parse the string with `ASCII Code` parts?